# Issue with changing label color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not a web developer but trying to fix something in code, so please excuse me if I am overlooking something.

I am trying to disable a checkbox and label when another checkbox is checked.

This is how my html looks like:

```
<dl id="someParent">
<dd><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"/>
<label for="checkbox1" data-localize="someText.name1" class="checkbox1">   </label>
</dd><dd>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2"/>
<label for="checkbox2" data-localize="someText.name2" class="checkbox2"> </label>
</dd><div class="clear"></div></dl>
```

JS:

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
 if( $("#checkbox1").is(':checked') ){
    $('#checkbox2').attr("disabled", true);
    $('label[data-localize="someText.name2"]').css("color", "red"); //This doesn't work 
  } else {
    $('#checkbox2').removeAttr('disabled');
    //Code to change label color. How, to access data-localize="someText.name2"? Where someText.name2 is defined in a json file as string, someText.name2: "This will be printed as label 1"
  }
});                            

$('#checkbox2').click(function() {
 if( $("#checkbox2").is(':checked') ){
   $('#checkbox1').attr('disabled', true);
    //Code to change label color. How, to access data-localize="someText.name1"? Where someText.name1 is defined in a json file as string, someText.name1: "This will be printed as label 2"
    } else {
       $('#checkbox1').removeAttr('disabled');
       $('label[data-localize="someText.name1"]').css("color", "black"); //This doesn't work 
    }
});
//My issue is I can not access and hence change color of "someText.name1/2" which is a label/text next to the Checkbox1/2. Disabling the Checkbox is not an issue but greying out the label next to checkbox is an issue.
```

In the original code, the program replaces someText.name1/2 with a mapping string from json file as a label.

I can make it work if I use a label in html(as seen in jsfiddle where I have used Checkbox1,2 as label), but not when code replaces the data-localize string from json file. The checboxes themselves are working correctly but the label doesnt change color.

Note: I can't change the architecture of code, therefore I have to use data-localize only. Also, this question is not about changing the color of label, but about how to access and change the label when data-localize is used.

Also, Checkbox1 and Checkbox2 labels are not in the original code instead they are generated dynamically replacing someText.name1 and someText.name2.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/w8s9rLme/34/

Comment: so, what does the `data-localize` attribute signify ?

Comment: EVen i don't know but looking in the code it looks like it is mapping to a string as:    someText.name1: "Some mapping string" defined in a json file

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve. so, `data-localize` is dynamic. Which label should get colored ? All the other labels under the `#someParent` ?

Comment: Yes, data-localize is dynamic. someText.name1 or someText.name2 should get colored.

Comment: You want to disable all other checkboxes with `data-localize` when one is c hecked?

Comment: Yes. There are two checkboxes and I want the other to be disabled along with the label when one is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was that no matter what method I used to change the color, it would not get changed. And the reason was because someone had used "!important" next to the color in css class, and hence no matter what i did the color of label didnt change.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify/generalize the code (*make it agnostic to the `data-localize` attribute*) a bit and also use a class for setting the colors.

```js
$('#someParent').on('change', ':checkbox', function(){
    var otherDD = $(this).closest('dd').siblings();
      
    otherDD.find(':checkbox')
           .prop('disabled', this.checked);
         
    otherDD.find('[data-localize]')
           .toggleClass('disabled-checkbox', this.checked);
});
```

```css
.disabled-checkbox{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ^^ added for demo ^^ -->

<dl id="someParent">
  <dd>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" />
    <label for="checkbox1" data-localize="someText.name1" class="checkbox1">Checkbox1</label>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" />
    <label for="checkbox2" data-localize="someText.name2" class="checkbox2">Checkbox2</label>
  </dd>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</dl>
```

Comment: The label Checkbox1 and Checkbox2 are not in original code. In original code the labels are generated dynamically and replaced by someText.name1.        But, I will give your solution a try.

Comment: @user353860 please post how the real html code looks on the system you are working.

Comment: I can not post the original code, but it is same as what is in the question description. Only thing I am missing is the json file which has definition for someText.name1/2, which is something like someText.name1: "Some text which gets printed as label"

Comment: Did you test the code ? because this code does not care about the text of the `label` elements, nor the values in the `data-localize` attributes. It does care for the `#someParent` id and that the `label` and `input` are inside a `dd` element.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the JS code above. My issue is I can not access and hence change color of "someText.name1" which is a label/text next to the Checkbox1.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still pretty unclear but I think I see where you're going. Here's an updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w8s9rLme/35/

To specifically answer your question: here's how you'd access the label:

```
var label = $('label.checkbox1').attr("data-localize");
```

And here's how you'd set it (using the data-localize to update the text):

```
$('label[data-localize="someText.name1"]').text(label);
```

Though, it would be better to reference it in a less-specific manner (assuming you may not know what data-localize will be).

```
$('label.checkbox1').text(label);
```

That's less reliant on what data-localize will be.